# Why frontend frameworks use server to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, module, frontend

Why do you host your React/Vue/Angular application(while developing) on a server when all the code you write runs on the client. I have read in some posts, that it is because of webpack, but webpack simply creates a bundle.js file that still runs on the client(gets attached as a script tag on the index.html file). I mean what is it that react app needs that can only be done on a server. If it is the hot reloading of webpack, do you really need a server for it and why

Answer (score 1):

- Servers can proxy / implement APIs
- Very different security restrictions are applied to documents loaded via FILE:// and via HTTP(S)://
- URL resolution for CSS, images, etc resolves differently when the base URL changes (`/` on a server and `/` on a filesystem are very different places)
- Using a server makes [hot reloading](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2016/03/24/introducing-hot-reloading) possible (you can't have a server push of new data without a server)